# Helm resolve .Release.Namespace that was passed into template file

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to set a var in my values.yaml that by default is set to `{{ .Release.Namespace }}`. But when I check the end result using `--dry-run` the value is `"{{ .Release.Namespace }}"`, and not the actual namespace.

If I set `ticker.secretNamespace` to a string i.e. `"foo"`, it works. How to get this working...

Thanks!

**values.yaml**

```
ticker:
  secretNamespace: "{{ .Release.Namespace }}"
```

**/tempaltes/prep.yaml**

```
...
      containers:
        - name: prep
          command:
            - /bin/bash
            - -exuc
            - |
              DEBUG A: {{ $.Release.Namespace }}
              {{- $namespace := $.Release.Namespace }}
              DEBUG B: {{ $namespace }}
              {{- with .Values.ticker }}
              {{- if not (eq .secretNamespace $namespace) }}
              DEBUG C: {{ .secretNamespace }}
              kubectl --namespace "{{ .secretNamespace }}" create secret ..."
              {{- end }}
              {{- end }}
...
```

**dry-run result**

```
      containers:
        - name: prep
          command:
            - /bin/bash
            - -exuc
            - |
              DEBUG A: test-ns
              DEBUG B: test-ns
              DEBUG C: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
              kubectl --namespace "{{ .Release.Namespace }}" create secret ...
```

Tried some different notation inside the `values.yaml`, but no luck.

```
secretNamespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
secretNamespace: {{ $.Release.Namespace }}
secretNamespace: .Release.Namespace
secretNamespace: "{{ .Release.Namespace | quote }}"
secretNamespace: "{{ .Release.Namespace | tpl }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve is not possible. Helm is not treating the `values.yaml` file as template to be resolved. Instead it uses values as input for the actual templates. So in your case it's just treating the `secretNamespace:` as a string to be copy/pasted.

If using `{{ $.Release.Namespace }}` is not enough for you, for example you want to allow user to specify namespace from values or command line, you can use `default` or write a helper template with more sophisticated logic.

See:
[default function](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-default-function)
[helm named templates](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach this by making `secretNamespace:` optional.  In `values.yaml` you might say

```yaml
ticker:
  # secretNamespace provides an alternate namespace for the Secret.
  # Defaults to the release namespace if unset.
  # secretNamespace: ...
```

Note in the last line that `secretNamespace` is commented.

Now in your template code, you can make a decision based on whether that value is set or not

```yaml
{{- with .Values.ticker }}
{{- if .secretNamespace }}
DEBUG C: {{ .secretNamespace }}
kubectl --namespace "{{ .secretNamespace }}" create secret ..."
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

This matches the logic in your existing template, except that "the current namespace" is specified by just omitting the value entirely.

Note that the behavior is different if you explicitly set the namespace

```bash
helm install -n a-namespace --set-string ticker.secretNamespace=a-namespace ...
```

You could use the `default` template function to get the actual namespace or the current one if it's unset, and then do the comparison

```yaml
{{- with .Values.ticker }}
{{- $secretNamespace := .secretNamespace | default .Release.Namespace }}
{{- if not (eq $secretNamespace .Release.Namespace }}
DEBUG C: {{ $secretNamespace }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

In principle you can use the [`tpl`](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function) template function to allow using Helm template syntax in the values, but you need to remember to consistently use it every place you might use the value.  It's not something you get "for free", and I'd use it sparingly.